# how to schedule meeting in MS Teams through Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I would like to create/read meetings on calender that shows in MS Teams. I have office 365 business essentials paid subscription that I use to log onto MS Teams.  Would like to clarify here below:

1)  the calender I see in MS Teams with my subscription plan mentioned above  is by default the outlook from office 365 subscription?

2) I want to automate schedule/read meetings on Teams calender. I dont see Teams API in MS Graph for this. What Graph APIsI can use? or will such calls be added in Teams Graph APIs?

3) Can MS Teams be integrated with google or any calender other than outlook?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, the calendar you see in Teams is exactly what you see in Outlook.
2. There is an API for reading and writing calendar items in Microsoft Graph, but there's currently no way to detect which ones are Teams meetings or to create Teams meetings (which, under the covers, is a few extra properties on the calendar item). That is on the backlog of the Outlook team to add to their Graph APIs and many of us inside Microsoft are very eager to see it.
3. No, Teams only supports the Exchange/Outlook calendar.

Comment: Hello Bill, thanks for reply. For reading "Team" meetings from outlook calendar: Do you think, I can parse calender item body and try to check if "teams meeting" link is available. If so, I can then identify that this meeting is a "Team" meeting? Perhaps until outlook team provides the explicit property as you mentioned above?

Comment: Further Continued: For scheduling a meeting: I observed that, when I click schedule meetings in Teams desktop client, it automatically adds "Join online Teams meeting" link.Perhaps this is also true for desktop outlook client with Teams plug-in. However, I dont see this option in outlook web client. I have office 365 business essential paid subscription. Can i call calender Graph APIs and schedule meeting with "Teams" link? I am trying to automate "Schedule a meeting" button in MS Teams desktop client app

Comment: @Bill Bliss - MSFT Is the API for creating Teams meeting now ready and available to use ?

Comment: Hello @TutuGeorge, Can you provide me link or some thing that help me to create team meeting using Graph API. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

It is now possible to create MS Teams meetings in two ways using the Graph API.

1. Executing a `POST` on the [`/me/events`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint.

   In the body of the request you need to provide `"isOnlineMeeting": true` and `"onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"` additional to the regular parameters.

   If you use this graph call you can invite other users and the meeting appears in the calendar of the organizer.
2. Executing a `POST` on the [`/me/onlineMeetings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint.

   (For parameters see the linked documentation)

   If you use this graph call *no invitations are sent* and the meeting *does not* appear in the calendar of the organizer. You would need alternative means to distribute the dial-in link, etc.

Comment: I created online meeting using graph api. I need to start the teams meeting from UI on behalf of user with userToken. Please help how can I achieve this.

Comment: Hi @Marvin
I followed step 1. I execute a POST on the /me/events endpoint and pass these two params in the body to get the team meeting join URL: "isOnlineMeeting": true, "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness". When I enable online meetings it gives me Skype join url, but i want the team's joinURL. Please help me in this case.

Comment: Hey @Paula maybe the user in question or even the whole tenant is set to SfBOnly-mode. I didn't experience this behaviour myself. In this case you would need to update the users coexistence mode in the teams admin center.